# Why is an unbounded subset of $\omega_1$ uncountable?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

(This is not a duplicate of the question in the link below. I want some more explanation but the question is made 7 years ago, so I don't expect to be answered if I just make a comment there.)

Let us say a set is an ordinal if it is well-ordered and transitive under the relation $\in$. $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal. I give the order topology on $\omega_1$. The statement I want to prove is:

> For each positive integer $n$, let $K_n$ be a compact subset of $\omega_1$. Assume $K_n$ has uncountably many elements. Then the intersection $K=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty K_n$ is an uncountable set.

I found a proof for the above proposition. It is in the link:

[The proof that $K$ is uncountable(Math stack exchange)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568030/prove-that-if-k-n-n-in-mathbbn-is-a-sequence-of-uncountable-compact-se)

In the answer, azarel says that:

> If $\xi<\omega_1$, then there is an ordinal $\gamma$ in the set $K_0 \cap K_1$ such that $\xi<\gamma$.

But I don't see why this is enough. All I can think is that I can choose $\gamma<\omega_1$, so $K_0 \cap K_1$ has at least countably many elements. How to proceed to the uncountability?

Comment: There are no such sets. Any compact subset of $\omega_1$ is bounded and so countable. You want subsets of $\omega_1 + 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $K_0\cap K_1$ were countable.  Then the ordinal $\xi=\bigcup K_0\cap K_1$ is a countable union of countable sets, so it is countable.  Thus $\xi<\omega_1$, so there exists $\gamma\in K_0\cap K_1$ such that $\xi<\gamma$.  But this is a contradiction, since $\gamma\in K_0\cap K_1$ means $\gamma\subseteq\xi$ so $\gamma\leq \xi$.

The point here is that $\omega_1$ has *uncountable cofinality*: you can't "reach the end of it" with a countable set, since the supremum of a countable set of countable ordinals will still be a countable ordinal and thus strictly below $\omega_1$.  So, any countable subset of $\omega_1$ is bounded in $\omega_1$.

Comment: It’s probably worth commenting that this requires the axiom of choice. Without AC, it’s possible for $\omega_1$ to be cofinal with $\omega.$

Comment: How do we know that $K_0\cap K_1\neq\emptyset$? That is, what is assumed here about these sets? If only uncountability, then $K_1$ may be every even ordinal below $\omega_1$, and $K_2$ every odd ordinal below $\omega_1$, and as such, they are disjoint. They cannot be compact in $\omega_1$, since they are unbounded in $\omega_1$.

Comment: @MadHatter: The sets are assumed to be compact.  (In any case, the question here is about why showing $K_0\cap K_1$ is unbounded is sufficient to prove it is uncountable.  A proof that $K_0\cap K_1$ is in fact unbounded can be found at the linked question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568030/prove-that-if-k-n-n-in-mathbbn-is-a-sequence-of-uncountable-compact-se.)