# Problem $2.18$, Rudin's RCA - Painfully Set Theoretic

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

> **Problem $2.18$**: This exercise requires more set-theoretic skill than the preceding ones. Let $X$ be a well-ordered uncountable set which has a last element $\omega_1$ such that every predecessor of $\omega_1$ has at most countably many predecessors. ("Construction": Take any well-ordered set which has elements with uncountably many predecessors, and let $\omega_1$ be the first of these; $\omega_1$ is called the first uncountable ordinal.) For $\alpha\in X$, let $P_\alpha[S_\alpha]$ be the set of all predecessors (successors) of $\alpha$, and call a subset of $X$ open if it is a $P_\alpha$ or an $S_\beta$ or a $P_\alpha \cap S_\beta$ or a union of such sets. Prove that $X$ is then a compact Hausdorff space. (Hint: No well-ordered set contains an infinite decreasing sequence.)
>
> 1. Prove that the complement of the point $\omega_1$ is an open set which is not $\sigma$-compact.
> 2. Prove that to every $f \in C(X)$ there corresponds an $\alpha\ne\omega_1$ such that $f$ is constant on $S_\alpha$.
> 3. Prove that the intersection of every countable collection $\{K_n\}$ of uncountable compact subsets of $X$ is uncountable. (Hint: Consider limits of increasing countable sequences in $X$ which intersect each $K_n$ in infinitely many points.)
>
> Let $\mathfrak M$ be the collection of all $E \subset X$ such that either $E \cup \{\omega_1\}$ or $E^c \cup \{\omega_1\}$ contains an uncountable compact set; in the first case, define $\lambda(E) = 1$; in the second case, define $\lambda(E) = O$. Prove that $\mathfrak M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains all Borel sets in $X$, that, $\lambda$ is a measure on $\mathfrak M$ which is not regular (every neighborhood of $\omega_1$ has measure $1$), and that $$f(\omega_1) = \int_X f\ d\lambda$$
> for every $f \in C(X)$. Describe the regular $\mu$ which Theorem 2.14 associates with this linear functional.

---

The problem certainly demands more set-theoretic skill than what I possess. My goal is to solve the problem in full, and that would start by understanding what it's saying. I request you to kindly help me with explanations/hints, and I will keep updating this post with my progress on this problem as I'm able to understand and do more parts of it.

---

**Thoughts:** First, they take $X$ to be a well-ordered (every non-empty subset has a least element) uncountable set with **last element** $\omega_1$. What do they mean by *last*? What is meant by "let $\omega_1$ be the first of these"?

They have defined exactly the open sets (i.e. the topology) in $X$. We must prove that $X$ is **compact** and **Hausdorff**. Hausdorff-ness is clear from Oliver's answer. For compactness, note that the topology on $X$ is the order topology, and by Theorem 27.1 of Munkres, we are done.

**Update:**
For (1): Note that $P_{\omega_1} = X\setminus \{\omega_1\}$, since $\omega_1$ is the last element. So the complement of $\omega_1$ is open. We want to show that it is not $\sigma$-compact. How do I do that?

For (2): Suppose $f\in C(X)$, i.e. $f$ is continuous on $X$. I'm not sure what the codomain of the function is, so I'm assuming $\mathbb C$. It looks like we want to find $z\in\mathbb C$ so that $f^{-1}(\{z\})$ is an $S_\alpha$ set for $\alpha < \omega_1$.

For (3): I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568030/prove-that-if-k-n-n-in-mathbbn-is-a-sequence-of-uncountable-compact-se), which seems to work.

Lastly, I could use hints on how to go about the final part of the problem about measures.

Thanks!

Comment: They're using "first" as synonymous with "least" and "last" as synonymous with "greatest". If there is an uncountable well ordered set such that some elements have uncountably many predecessors, then the set of such elements is nonempty, and therefore has a smallest element (since the set is well ordered). Call it $\omega_1$. So $\omega_1$ has uncountably many predecessors, but any predecessor of $\omega_1$ has only countably many predecessors, since $\omega_1$ was the smallest element with uncountably many predecessors.

Comment: Brilliant - that makes sense! I understand the construction of $X$ now, though I guess that would not help in proving that it is compact and Hausdorff, right? Perhaps we can forget about the construction and just work with the properties that Rudin says $X$ has. @Joe

Comment: From the construction, I think that you'll just need to use that that every element less than $\omega_1$ has countably many predecessors, but $\omega_1$ has uncountably many predecessors. However, I haven't done topology in many years, so I'm not sure the next step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The juicy parts (the compactness of $X$ and the analysis on $X$ are left for you since you are very enthusiastic on seeing this problem though and may need help only with a few details here and there.

0. $X=[0,\omega_1]$ with the order topology is a Compact and Hausdorff space:

**a.** Compactness if $X$: If you are not well versed in this business of orders and ordinals, a quick read though Point Set Topology books will help you. There are many classic books. Here is just a reference if you need to freshen up on order relations, the week order principle and the order topology: Munkres, J. R. *Topology*, 2ns ed., pages 24-28 (definitions and examples); pages 63-66 (well order principle, what it is and there stuff); pages 84-86 (order topology); and pages 172-174 (proof of compactness of intervals of the form $[a,b]$ in linearly ordered spaces with the supremum property, of which your space $X$ and also the real line are examples). All this will give you  more than enough about the topology of $X=[0,\omega_1]=P_{\omega_1}\cup\{\omega_1\}$.

**b.** $X=[0,\omega_1]$ is Hausdorff: suppose $x,y\in X$ and $x\leq y$, w.l.o.g assume $x<y$. If $y$ is a successor of $x$ then $[0,y)=P_y$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ and $(x,\omega_1]=S_x$ is an open neighborhood of $y$; moreover, $[0,y)\cap(x,\omega_1]=\{z\in X: x<z<y\}=\emptyset\}$ (because $y$ is a successor or $x$). If $y$ is not a successor of $x$, then there is $z\in X$ between $x$ and $y$,that is, there is $z\in X$ such that $x<z<y$. Then $[0,z)$ is and open neighborhood of $x$, and $(z,\omega_1]$ is an open neighborhood of $y$ and $[0,z)\cap(z,\omega_1]=\emptyset$.

---

1. $[0,\omega_1)$ is not $\sigma$-compact:

Since open sets of the form $(x,y)=[0,y)\cap(x,\omega_1]$, and of the form $[0,y)$,  with $0\leq x<y<\omega_1$, are countable (why?) all compact subsets of $[0,\omega_1)$ are countable (being covered by finite union of such sets). The union of coubtable sets, being countable, can't cover $[0,\omega_1)$ which is uncountable by the choice of $\omega_1$.

***Obs:***
**c.** A consequence of (1) is that for any compact set $K\subset[0,\omega_1]$, $K$ is   uncountable iff $\omega_1\in K$ and $\omega_1$ is a cluster point of $K$, i.e. for any $\alpha<\omega_1$, $(\alpha,\omega_1)\cap K\neq\emptyset$. Indeed, if $\omega_1$ is an isolated point of $K$, then $K\setminus\{\omega_1\}$ is  a compact set contained in $[0,\omega_1)$ and so, $K=(K\setminus\{\omega_1\})\cup\{\omega_1\}$ is countable. Conversely, if $K$ is uncountable, then $K$ is not contained in any set of the form $[0,\alpha]$, $\alpha<\omega_1$; hence $K\cap(\alpha,\omega_1)\neq\emptyset$.

**d.** Incidentally, the observation above also shows that any increasing sequence $A=\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset[0,\omega_1)$ converges to a point $\beta\in[0,\omega_1)$. Indeed, $A$ is bounded above by $\omega_1$. Let $b$ be the first element of $\{\beta\in X:a_n\leq \beta,\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}b$ and so, $\{b,a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is countable and compact. Hence $b\neq\omega_1$.

---

3. The intersection of a countable collection of uncountable compact sets is uncountable:

Suppose $\mathcal{K}=\{K_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a sequence of uncountable compact sets in $X$. Observation (c) above implies that $\omega_1$ is a cluster point of each $K_n$. Consider first $K_1\cap K_2$. Let $\alpha_0<\omega_1$. Then there is $\alpha_1\in K_1$ such that $\alpha_0<\alpha_1<\omega_1$. In turn, this implies that there is $\alpha_2\in K_2$ such that $a_1<\alpha_2<\omega_1$. Proceeding by induction, we obtain a sequence $A=\{\alpha_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ such that $\alpha_n<\alpha_{n+1}$, $\alpha_n\in K_1$ for $n\equiv1\operatorname{mod}2$, and $\alpha_n\in K_2$ for $n\equiv0\operatorname{mod}2$. Observation (d) implies that $A$ converges to some $\beta\in[0,\omega_1)$. Clearly $\beta$ is a cluster point of both $K_1$ and $K_2$; hence, $\beta\in K_1\cap K_2$ ( $K_j$, $j=1,2$ is closed). Define $K'_n=\bigcap^n_{\ell=1}K_\ell$. Then, each  $K'_n$ is compact and uncountable, and  since $\bigcap^\infty_{n=1}K'_n=\bigcap^\infty_{n=1}K_n$,  we may assume without loss of generality that the sequence $\mathcal{K}$ is monotone non increasing, which we do now. Arguing as before, we get that for any $\alpha\in[0,\omega_1)$, we find a sequence increasing sequence $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ such that $\alpha<a_n\in K_n\cap[0,\omega_1)$. Then, we have that $b=\sup_na_n\in (\alpha,\omega_1)$ is a cluster point each $K_n$; hence $b\in K=\bigcap_nK_n$. This shows that $\omega_1$ is a cluster point of $K$, and by (c), $K$ is uncountable.

---

2. For every $f\in\mathcal{C}(X)$, there is $\beta_f\in[0,\omega_1)$ such that $f$ is a constant on $(\beta,\omega_1]$:

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$,     the set $U_n=\big\{\alpha\in X:|f(\alpha)-f(\omega_1)|<\frac1n\big\}$ is open and contains $\omega_1$. Let $\alpha_1\in U_1\setminus\{\omega_1\}$. Once $\alpha_1<\ldots<\alpha_n<\omega_1$ have been constructed, choose $\alpha_{n+1}\in U_n\cap(\alpha_n,\omega_1)$ (this is possible since any open set containing $\omega_1$ contains an interval of the form $(\alpha,\omega_1)$. By (d), $\beta=\sup_n\alpha_n\in[0,\omega_1)$. It follows that for all $\beta<\gamma\leq\omega_1$, $f(\gamma)=f(\omega_1)$, for $\gamma\in\bigcap_nU_n$.

---

All this take care of the topological aspects of the problem.

4. I leave to the OP to show that the family
   $$\mathcal{F}=\{E\subset X: \text{either}\,E\cup\{\omega_1\}\,\text{or}\, E^c\cup\{\omega_1\}\,\text{contains an uncountable compact set}\}$$
   is a $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets.
   **Hint:**

- Clearly $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under complementation, and $X\in\mathcal{F}$.
- (3) and observation (c) will be useful to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under countable intersections.
- It will be useful to check that open sets in $X$ are countable union of sets of the form $(x,y)$, $[0,y)$ and $(x,\omega_1]$, where $0\leq x<y\leq \omega_1$.

5. I also leave the details that $\lambda$ is indeed a measure on $\mathscr{F}$.

Once the OP proves this, it is easy to check that  that for any $0\leq a<\omega_1$, we have $\lambda\big((a,\omega_1)\big)=1$, $\lambda(\{\omega_1\})=0$,  and $\lambda([0,a])=0$.
From this, and part (2) of the OP, it follows that for any $f\in\mathcal{C}(X)$,
$$\int_X f\,d\lambda=\int_{(\alpha_f,\omega_1]}f\,d\lambda=f(\omega_1)\lambda\big((\alpha_f,\omega_1]\big)=f(\omega_1)$$

The lack of regularity of $\lambda$ is also easy to check as $\lambda(\{\omega_1\})=0$ and $\lambda(U)=1$ for any open neighborhood $U$ of $\omega_1$.

---

The regular measure $\mu$ obtained from application of Riesz-Markov representation theorem to the linear map $f\mapsto f(\omega_1)$ satisfies the property $\mu(A)=\mathbb{1}_{A}(\omega_1)$ for every Borel set $A$ (this is the $\delta$-measure supported by $\{\omega_1\}$).

Comment: Compactness: $X$ is well-ordered, so it has the least upper bound property. $X = [0,\omega_1]$ (a closed interval), so by Theorem 27.1 of Munkres, $X$ is compact. Correct?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: That is Correct.

Comment: If possible, could you say something about the remaining parts of the problem? @OliverDiaz

Comment: @OliverDiaz: I have a couple of questions: (1) In you arguments for observation (d) why is $b$ the limit of $a_n$. (2) In your argument for solving part (3) of the OP, why does $b=\sup_na_n$ exist?

Comment: Hi @JeanL. To answer you first question, notice that any open set (in the order topology) that contains $b$ contains an nonempty *interval* of the form $(x,y)$ with $0\leq x<b\leq y$ (the *intervals* $[0,x)$ and $(y,\omega_1]$ form a subbasis for the order topology). Since $X$ is well ordered, $(x,y)$ has a first element, say $c$. Clearly $c<b$, so, there is $a_{n_c}$ such that $c<a_{n_c}$ by definition of $b$. The assumption on $\{a_n\}$ implies that  $c<a_{n_c}<a_n$ for all $n> n_c$. That answers your first question (***to be continued...***)

Comment: @JeanL....(***continuation***) Your second question is also a consequence of the *well orderedness* of $X$: every non-empty set $A\subset X$ that is upper bounded admits a supremum in $X$. To see this, suppose $A\neq\emptyset$, and that for some $\beta\in X$, $a\leq \beta$ for all $a\in A$. Then the set $\{\beta\in X: a\leq\beta\,\forall a\in A\}$ is a nomepty set and so, it has a first element, say $b$. I leave it to you to check that $b$ is the least upper bound of $A$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz (A) I see that $[0,\omega_1] = P_{\omega_1}$ is an open set, and also that every $(x,y)$ is countable (it is contained in $P_y$, a countable set). However, I don't see how you have concluded that every compact subset of $[0,\omega_1)$ is countable.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: There are several ways to see this. This is how I thought about that. If $K\subset[0,\omega_1)$ is compact, then $K$ is covered by finite sets of the form $(x,y)$ or $[0,y)$, where $0\leq x<y<\omega_1$, each of which is countable. Thus, $K$ is itself countable (this includes finites sets which I consider, albeit not explicitly, as countable).

Comment: Hi Oliver. Just want to let you know that I will take longer to respond to this answer and ask you follow-up questions if any. I just got vaccinated and the side effects have been bad; I believe I might need to take a couple of days off.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: sure, just get rest and we'll talk when you have further questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For Hausdorff, you can use that $X$ is linearly ordered. So if $\alpha<\beta$, use a combination of predecessor/successor open sets to separate them. Keep in mind that $\alpha$ has an immediate successor but $\beta$ might not have an immediate predecessor.

For compactness, assume the open sets are $P$'s or $S$'s since they form a basis. Then it is helpful to notice that the two types of open sets are nested: if $\alpha\leq\beta$, then $P_\alpha\subseteq P_\beta$ and $S_\beta\subseteq S_\alpha$. Then split the open cover into the two types and think about how much they cover. The well-foundedness of the ordering will help with the $S_\alpha$.

As an aside, if you are still thinking about what the ordering looks like, it is like an uncountable version of the ordering of the natural numbers 0,1,2,...$\omega$ where you put an infinite number $\omega$ on the end which is larger than all of the finite numbers. So here the open sets $P_n$ are $0,1,2,...n$ and the open sets $S_n$ are $n,n+1,n+2,....\omega$, and you get the whole space or just $\omega$ if you pick $\omega$ instead of a finite number.